# AnnimationDrawable not start !

Tags: android, animation, drawable

I tried to do an annimation this way:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startAnimation();
}

void startAnimation(){
    AnimationDrawable animDrawable = new AnimationDrawable();
    animDrawable.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wait_connextion_0),100);
    animDrawable.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wait_connextion_1), 100);
    animDrawable.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wait_connextion_2), 100);
    animDrawable.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wait_connextion_3), 100);

    animDrawable.setOneShot(false); 
    ImageView waitIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.waitIV);
    waitIV.setBackgroundDrawable(animDrawable); 
    animDrawable.start();
}
```

but it does not work, can you tell me what's the problem please :-(

Comment: This can be done only in Thread

Comment: thank you i gfind the solution in the link http://androidforums.com/application-development/11620-programmatic-frame-frame-animation-examle-animationdrawable.html